# MultiView application for iphone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone, iphone

I am new to iPhone development and I have to develop a multiview application for iPhone.

I want to do the following:

1. On click of a button in the main window, open a new view that has a toolbar with items and a tab bar in it, with some text data in between from a service.
2. If the user click on any of the toolbar item, a new view should pop up with a table view.

It would be a great help if any one can give me direction as how to proceed with this. I am confused with the controller flow.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to learn about this is from the source, check out Apple's document on [View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).